# Like a video in Youtube without API key?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have a app with button as like-button of youtube and videoId of a video.
Before I get sessionid, cookies from webviewclient with a google account.
How to like that video then video appear in my likelist video in youtube without Youtube API?
I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

the [Video.rate](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) method will allow you to submit a like or dislike on a video though the YouTube API.

This method does not require an API key it does though requier authorization

You Will need to use Oauth2 to authorize the user to your application who will be making the link

Using one of the following scopes.

[image]